# Codecademy Ruby yield keyword

Tags: ruby

I am working on an exercise for the Ruby section of the codecademy website. The section I am on has to do with yield statements. This is the original code for the exercise.

```
def yield_name(name)
  puts "In the method! Let's yield."
  yield("Kim")
  puts "In between the yields!"
  yield(name)
  puts "Block complete! Back in the method."
end

yield_name("Eric") { |n| puts "My name is #{n}." }
```

Here are the instructions for this challenge: Call yield_name with your name as a parameter. Make sure to pass in a block that puts "My name is #{your name here}!"

Here is what I tried initially:

```
def yield_name(name)
  puts "In the method! Let's yield."
  yield("Patrick")
  puts "In between the yields!"
  yield(name)
  puts "Block complete! Back in the method."
end

yield_name("Patrick") { |n| puts "My name is #{n}." }
```

When I submit this, I am told that I need to call yield_name a second time with my name in the block. So here is what I tried next:

```
def yield_name(name)
  puts "In the method! Let's yield."
  yield_name("Patrick")
  puts "In between the yields!"
  yield(name)
  puts "Block complete! Back in the method."
end

yield_name("Patrick") { |n| puts "My name is #{n}." }
```

When I submit this, I get an infinite loop of the first statement: "In the method! Let's yield." and everything else is ignored. I need help understanding what is wrong with my code, and perhaps some clarification on the yield statement. I understand that it is yielding execution to another block of code, but that is the extent of my understanding.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You weren't really supposed to change the original code:

```
def yield_name(name)
  puts "In the method! Let's yield."
  yield("Kim")
  puts "In between the yields!"
  yield(name)
  puts "Block complete! Back in the method."
end

yield_name("Eric") { |n| puts "My name is #{n}." }
```

What you're supposed to do seems to be add a new call to `yield_name` passing your name as paramater, in your case:

```
yield_name("Patrick") { |n| puts "My name is #{n}." }
```

The whole code should now look like:

```
def yield_name(name)
  puts "In the method! Let's yield."
  yield("Kim")
  puts "In between the yields!"
  yield(name)
  puts "Block complete! Back in the method."
end

yield_name("Eric") { |n| puts "My name is #{n}." }

# Now call the method with your name!
yield_name("Patrick") { |n| puts "My name is #{n}." }
```

Comment: Thank you very much. It seems like all the questions I'm asking are amateur, but I'm sure I'll get the hang of everything.